# Trying to get td row text when clicking on td after it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, traversal

I want to get the contents of the row when I click on the div in the row after it

HTML:

```
<td class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2">10</td>
<td class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2">
    <div class="ms-chkmark-container">
        <div class="ms-chkmark-container-centerer"><span class="ms-cui-img-16by16 ms-cui-img-cont-float" unselectable="on" style="z-index:0"><img id="2,10,chk" liid="10" shouldanimate="1" lid="{00124E2C-BFCD-4501-8668-EFAF8E6416D2}" tabindex="0" title="Mark task complete." class="js-chkmark ms-chkmark-notcomplete" src="/_catalogs/theme/Themed/626BDBFA/spcommon-B35BB0A9.themedpng?ctag=11" unselectable="on" hascheckmarkhandler="1"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

JS:

```
var itemID = $("div .ms-chkmark-container").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).closest("td").prev().html();
    console.log(id);
    return id;
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q7Zfv/6/

Comment: And what's the problem in doing so?

Comment: I think your example is working fine.. what is your question exactly? http://jsfiddle.net/zN2Xs/

Comment: Oh, well there was nothing in my log so I don't think it worked. Also, the prev(), wouldn't that grab the parent td tag and not the one above it?

Comment: What's the purpose of setting `var itemID` ?

Comment: I don't know. I need to store the ID to use somewhere else so I thought that's how i'd do it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just go for parent() instead of prev()?

```
var id = $(this).parent().prev().html();
```

Haven't tried it though, but should work.

You can also point the click to the td itself and use $(this).

Answer (score -1):

```
<td class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2 itemid">10</td>
<td class="ms-cellstyle ms-vb2">
    <div class="ms-chkmark-container">
        <div class="ms-chkmark-container-centerer"><span class="ms-cui-img-16by16 ms-cui-img-cont-float" unselectable="on" style="z-index:0"><img id="2,10,chk" liid="10" shouldanimate="1" lid="{00124E2C-BFCD-4501-8668-EFAF8E6416D2}" tabindex="0" title="Mark task complete." class="js-chkmark ms-chkmark-notcomplete" src="/_catalogs/theme/Themed/626BDBFA/spcommon-B35BB0A9.themedpng?ctag=11" unselectable="on" hascheckmarkhandler="1"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>


  ("div .ms-chkmark-container").click(function () {
    var id=$(this).parent().prev(".itemid").html();
    }
```